# Помогите написатиь драйвер для звуковой карты

Tags: windows, драйвер

Помогите пожалуйста написатиь драйвер для звуковой карты Yamaha 744 под windows 7 64-бит. Дайте хотя бы ориентировки, скелет, как написать драйвер на Visual Studio C.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Скелет вам сделает Visual Studio, если вы создадите новый проект Windows Driver. Если вы не видите такой тип проекта, запустите инсталляцию Visual Studio и отметьте опциональный компонент Drivers, или WDK (Windows Drivers Kit), не помню точно.

Примеры драйверов найдете здесь: https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-driver-samples (Windows drivers samples)

Драйвер, похожий на ваш: https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/tree/master/audio/sysvad (audio/sysvad)

Для начала прочитайте его описание: https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/blob/master/audio/sysvad/README.md (readme.md).

Документация для разработчиков: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ (Windows hardware developer documentation)

И наконец, главный форум разработчиков драйверов:

OSR.com: https://www.osr.com/

OSR Developer Community: https://community.osr.com/

А также учтите, что этот пример написан на WDM, лучше использовать KMDF. Возможно, есть Audio примеры на KDMF, может быть, найдете подходящий.

Comment: а для создания  проекта Windows Driver, какая редакция VS подойдет? 2008/2010 Express не подойдет?

Comment: а вы можете такой драйвер написать отталкиваяь от готового примера? на пользу всего общеста, а я бы мог немного заплатить

Comment: а вот под Линукс как-то смогли написать без спецификаций, под Ямахи есть драйвер в сборнике ALSA, автор Jaroslav Kysela <perex@perex.cz>

Comment: а если я вам подарю новую Yamaha 744 это может заинтересовать?